# Distribution of spectral types of "giant" stars

Tags: star

I'm looking for the distribution of spectral types in the "giant" star category. This category is defined as basically B and O main sequence stars and any star that is larger than main sequences outside of it.

My first thought was that the M, K, G, F, and A type distribution were the same as they are in the main sequence but then I realized M has to be dropped, and then i'm not quite sure how K, G, F, and A types evolve and usually only Red Giants are mentioned and I couldn't find numbers for the giants so I'm stuck.

To be clear, I want to know the percentage of giant stars that are in each of the spectral types. So if there are 1000 stars in a given area and 100 giant stars in that areas I only want to know the percentage of each spectral type of the stars in that 100.

Comment: I can't work out what it is you want to know, or what you've done to find an answer.

Comment: @RobJeffries Does that new added last paragraph help?

Comment: So essentially you want to know the temperature distribution of giants, where your definition of giant includes main sequence OB stars.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I see what you want.

What I did was take the revised Hipparcos catalogue and select all stars closer than 50pc. At this distance there should be a *complete* sample of the types of stars you were interested in. I can plot an absolute magnitude versus colour diagram for these 7096 stars (see below) and use this to select giants and OB main sequence stars.

I do this by using data from chapter 2 of [Zombeck (1992)](http://ads.harvard.edu/books/hsaa/toc.html), I define O and B main sequence stars to have $B-V<0$ and $M_V<5$ (to exclude hot white dwarfs). Evolved giants are selected (a bit arbitrarily) to lie significantly above the main sequence.

[image: Stars closer than 50pc]

Then I can plot a frequency histogram of the B-V values of those stars and label them with spectral types, again according to tables in Zombeck (1992).
The result is seen below.

[image: Distribution of "giant stars"]

Of these 235 stars: None are O stars, 29 are B stars, about 120 are G giants, about 80 are K giants and only 2-3 are M giants

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something. I thought that Red Gian and Supergiants were the dominant, but your answer seems to indicate Yellow Giants are the dominant and there are barely any Reds...

Comment: @Durakken It is what it is. Of course if you were interested in a magnitude limited sample, rather than a volume limited sample, the answer might be different. Perhaps I have misinterpreted what you meant bt "stars in a given area"?

Comment: @Durakken Also, all of the giants are redder than the Sun.

Comment: i think the issue is that I'm thinking that there are a class for each spectral type, when it now seems that all spectral types are wrapped up in the terms/classes Red Giant, Red Supergiant, and Yellow Hypergiants which are special specific instances... So my question isn't right to what i needed to know, but your answer helped with what i really did.

Comment: @Durakken There are no "hypergiants" or "supergiants" in the sample above. These are rare (but luminous).

Comment: Astounding answer!

Comment: @Durakken When I find a moment I will add the answer for a magnitude limited sample.

Comment: Should I be amused that the numbers of types of stars in your answer does not add up to 235? but 232, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Durakken "about 120 are G giants, about 80 are K giants". Why do you think the numbers should add up exactly?

Comment: Why wouldn't they add up?

Comment: @Durakken Because I don;t know exactly where the boundary is and have not provide spurious 3 significant figure accuracy.

Comment: Ahh I see. I figured it was something like that.